# Calculate date difference in Drupal views

Tags: php, date, drupal-7, drupal-views

I need to calculate the difference between two Date fields in Drupal 7 views.
How do I do this? 
Have installed Views PHP but can not figure out how the Date Fields works.
I have search for this and tried some snippets but now I give up.
The two Date fields in the node are:
Start: 2016-02-06 07:15
Slut:   2016-02-09 16:15
The code snippet I have tried is:

```
$start=$row->field_start;
$slut=$row->field_slut;
$diff=$slut-$start;
print_r($diff);
```

This only result in 0. The values for the two variables are both 4 when I get them in the views PHP field?
Have tried both the Date and Date (Unix timestamp) with the same result.
/Chrotto

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
// make sure the values you are getting here are correct
$start_value = $row->field_start;
$end_value = $row->field_slut;

$start_date = new DateObject($start_value);
$end_date = new DateObject($end_value);
$duration = $start_date->diff($end_date);
```

Comment: Thanks,Sorry to say this did not work.It seams to be somthing wrong with the field values given by the Available variables. I have three fields: start, slut and namn. When I catch them in PHP fields like $row->field_start, $row->field_slut and $row->field_namn all deliver only the Nid number!

Comment: When putting return $data as value code and then put print:r($data) as output code I see all I need in an array.

Answer (score 0):

I switch to my Drupal 8 installation (shall port anyway) and found this on php.net that worked:

```
$datetime1 = date_create($row->field_start);
$datetime2 = date_create($row->field_stop);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a days %h hours och %i minuts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was worked hours I want to get and after some more digging I found a better way to do this:

```
 $start = strtotime($row->field_start);
 $stop = strtotime($row->field_stop); 
 $time_elapsed=$stop-$start;
 $minutes=$time_elapsed/60;
 $hours=$minutes/60;
 echo $hours;
```